# AngularJS nesting two function calls

Tags: angularjs, function, asynchronous

I have a function which validates startDate and endDate by calling function validatePositions and on initialization i want to call this function but sometimes endDate call returns faster than startDate which is incorrect for my case.

```
function validatePositions (date) {
    validatePositions (date)
            .then(function (response) {
               if (response.data) {
                  hideWarning();
               } else if (!warningShowed()) {
                  displayWarningMessage();
               }
    });
}
```

Init function looks like that :

```
function init() {
        $q.all(validationService.validatePositions(startDate)).then(function () {
            wizardService.validatePositions(endDate);})

    }
```

How I can nest this call to make them return at the same time or first startDate call then endDate call?

Comment: What about these functions hideWarning();,displayWarningMessage();?

Answer (score 0):

Do not handle your promise in your service, rather, just return it and handle it in the controller. Something like:

```
function validatePositions (date) {
    return $resource(url, {date: date}).get()
}
```

and then in your controller do:

```
init(){
    validateService.validatePositions(startDate).$promise.then(
        function(success){
            if(success.data){
              //do somethig
              validateService.validatePositions(endDate).$promise.then(
                  function(success){
                     if(success.data){
                     //do somethig
                     }
                  }
              }
           }
        }
        function(error){
          //do something
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return promise. Change your code like below.

```
function validatePositions (date) {
  return validatePositions(date).then(function (response) {                   
                  hideWarning();
           return response.data;
    }),function(error) {
         displayWarningMessage();
    });
   }
```